# LD_LIBRARY_PATH, the shared lib path in linux

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I wrote a shared object, say `libsd.so`, and I put `libsd.so` and its header file `sd.h` in `~/lib`.

Here is another program using `libsd.so`, say `test.c`, then compile it like this:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c -I~/lib -L~/lib -lsd
```

Then I run `test` like this:

```
$ ./test
./test_sd: error while loading shared libraries: libsd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I set `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.`, then it works. But if I `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and put `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib` in my `~/.bashrc`, then `source ~/.bashrc`, again it doesn't work for `./test`, WHY?

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib` is difference from putting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib` in `~/.bashrc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the export your declared LD_LIBRARY_PATH is only valid in the script (.bashrc).
With the export it should work, but it is usually not a good idea to set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH like this.

If you don't want to install your library in the system path (e.g. /usr/lib) you should probably use a script that sets LD_LIBARAY_PATH locally and starts your application.

Comment: Well, why it's not a good idea? could you plz elaborate on that?

Comment: You can see here, why it is not a good idea: http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html However, it seems, that you shouldn't even use it in a script, but rather use the -R option

Comment: I'm using Fedora not Solaris, But is there a `-R` in gcc?

Comment: On Fedora there should be -rpath, that should do pretty much the same thing, even though I actually do not know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$HOME/lib` instead of `~/lib` - it *should* be the same but I've seen cases where `~` wasn't expanded properly when used in an variable assignment.

To check, try `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which gives you the current value.

Re `export`: If you omit the `export`, then the variable is only known to the current shell process and will not be exported to child processes. So if you omit it, `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will get the value because the variable is expanded by the shell *before* the `echo` command/builtin has a chance to do anything. But `./test` won't see it because it's not exported to the new subprocess.

Comment: Replaced, I `source ~/.bashrc`, and `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gives the current value, do you mean if I want `./test` to work, I should still `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Yes, you always have to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or it will have no effect.