# "No such file or directory" linker error, LD_LIBRARY_PATH set correctly

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, embedded-linux, ld

Some background: I'm using an embedded board (the SolidRun Cubox-i4 Pro), and have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it using an image obtained on SolidRun's community forums.

This particular board has a Vivante GC2000 graphics driver that advertises OpenCL support. However, the GPU driver is proving to be a pain. I found binaries for all the required libraries, but when I try to run a small test executable built against them, I get this familiar error:

```
cubox@cubox:~/cltest$ g++ cltest.cpp -lOpenCL -lGAL
cubox@cubox:~/cltest$ ./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenCL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I double-check the path of the library:

```
cubox@cubox:~/cltest$ ls /usr/lib/libOpenCL*   
/usr/lib/libOpenCL.so
```

And I double-check my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable:

```
cubox@cubox:~/cltest$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib
```

OK, so clearly the issue is not that it can't find the library, but that there's some kind of incompatibility, and the error is being misleading (I've seen this before). So I try this:

```
cubox@cubox:~/cltest$ file /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so 
/usr/lib/libOpenCL.so: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

...and compare that with what I just compiled:

```
cubox@cubox:~/cltest$ file a.out 
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=fcd06f947198f92f43f364874fcef66a6303e7b4, not stripped
```

They look similar, except that one mentions `for GNU/Linux 2.6.32`. I then remembered that the driver came with some pre-compiled test apps, so I ran one of them:

```
cubox@cubox:/opt/viv_samples/cl11/fft$ ./fft 
-bash: ./fft: No such file or directory
```

...and checked its `file` info:

```
cubox@cubox:/opt/viv_samples/cl11/fft$ file fft
fft: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, stripped
```

So one is for `GNU/Linux 2.6.32`, and the other is for `GNU/Linux 2.6.31`.

Questions:

1. Is that why nothing will execute or "find" the libraries?
2. If so, what are my options? Can I force them to run somehow?
3. Is there another command I can run to learn more about the libraries?

EDIT in response to answer(s):

ldd output:

```
cubox@cubox:~/cltest$ ldd a.out 
    libOpenCL.so => not found
    libGAL.so => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0x76ea1000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x76e80000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76d99000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x76d2c000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76f5f000)
```

Executable permissions were already correct (`-rwxrwxr-x` for mine, `-rwxr-xr-x` for the fft app).

Comment: Perhaps you have a similar problem as described in this question/answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76490/no-such-file-or-directory-on-an-executable-yet-file-exists-and-ldd-reports-al

Comment: It can be that libOpenCL.so is found, but one of its dependencies is missing, try running ldd on libOpenCL.so itself

Answer (score 1):

run ldd on your executable to check what shared libraries it wants to pull in.

Also, to run a program it needs an executable bit to be set in the permitions

$ ls -la fft

$ chmod a+x fft
./fft

Comment: system doesn't let me to leave a comment to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the problem is that you didn't `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so it's only set in your shell and not exported to the `a.out` child process.

See [LD_LIBRARY_PATH, the shared lib path in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412296/ld-library-path-the-shared-lib-path-in-linux)